# Rename files found after search in Thunar

Tags: xubuntu, xfce

Thunar has some option to find files (like Explorer has for Windows users). However, the found files are not displayed like other files in Thunar. The option to rename a file is missing there, like most other options from the context menu of Thunar. I can open a found file with a double click, but where are the other options usually available after a right click?

**Would it be possible to make Thunar show all context menu options also for the results of Find File?**

If Thunar can’t do that: **Is there some other GUI file browser usable under Xubuntu which easily lets me search for files (using wildcards in the name) and gives me the option to give better names to found files?**

Comment: You can install and use Nautilus, the default Gnome file manager. It's not so bad. PCManFM, Lubuntu file manager, is not so interative as Nautilus. Dolphin is for kubuntu, this I didn't like so much (personal opinion).

Comment: Catfish is often used to search for files via a custom action. If so right click on the file to be renamed and select "Show in File Manager". Once the file manger opens the correct folder. Navigate to the file, right click on it and select "Rename".

Comment: So it is not Thunar but Catfish is called from Thunar? I did not know that but I saw from calling info that this is the case. - Yes, I saw the possibility of „show in file manager“. But if the directory is a big one finding the file is not very easy since it is not already highlighted, it is just plain opening the folder. - Is there an alternative to Catfish or a newer version which already does what I want? My catfish called from Thunar is version 1.4.2.

Comment: @Redbob: Thank you fore your hint. I installed Nautilus and it does exactly what I was after. However, if I start it from a command linne, I get this eroor message: ** (nautilus:6221): WARNING **: Couldn't connect to accessibility bus: Failed to connect to socket /tmp/dbus-RxXDFkb2sB: Verbindungsaufbau abgelehnt. It works nevertheless. Any idea about this message?

Comment: After I installed Nautilus via software center, I got version "GNOME nautilus 3.14.3". This seems to be an older version and it has the disadvantge that one can not set the date display to ISO format. - strange! So I better stay with Thunar and use Nautlus not as my default file browser, despite it has the better find mechanism. But I'll keep the isntalled copy for find operations.

Comment: Hanßen, this message is harmful. This happens because nautilus is installed in a no-Gnome environment. You don't need to worry about it.

Answer (score 0):

Linux (Ubuntu as extension) has the ability to work and host technologies and tools from several graphical interfaces. Although we know that each interface has its own file manager, there is no problem in testing, approving and adopting another one.

In this issue, I suggest you to install [Nautilus](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Nautilus), a native file manager for Gnome and Unity. In my opinion, he is more mature and interactive. Just 
`sudo apt install nautilus` and you will have it in your Ubuntu flavor.

You can also extend the scope of Nautilus by installing [extensions](https://developer.gnome.org/libnautilus-extension/stable/).

Answer (score 0):

I finally found [xfe](https://sourceforge.net/projects/xfe/) which can among other things find a file including finding files by a keyword from its content.

[Xfe](https://sourceforge.net/projects/xfe/) has a context menu with more choices on what to do with found items, among others rename.